# Can I compare two other correlation coefficients in one meta-analysis?

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

I am in the process of initial research into the relationship between blood pressure and the PPG signal parameter. I have two groups of articles that describe: 1) the correlation coefficient between the estimated and reference blood pressure and 2) the correlation coefficient between the blood pressure and the PPG signal parameter. My question is: is it possible to compare these groups with each other in one meta-analysis? Or should I analyze the two groups separately and then compare them? PrintScreen with sample data below.

[image]

Comment: If one is the correlation between X and Y and the other is between X and Z why to you want to compare them?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question... In any case multivariate meta-analysis might offer you a way to perform similar analyses... For instance have a look here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvmeta/mvmeta.pdf